# Obscure fantasy movie involving flying sea-galleons and a time weapon

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

Been trawling the internet for hours, can't find any trace or reference of this movie. Not really sure what station I saw it on (only once), but it was probably Sci-Fi Channel (mind you, a very long time ago:

Movie opens with flying ships (sailing galleons), that proceed to siege a towering city. The city fires back with its own cannons, and drives the invaders away. The main protagonist is a young boy who longs to be a knight... or this movie's equivalent thereof. He has an older brother who is already recognized as a warrior. The boy lives in the city that successfully repelled this siege.

The king of this city has some sort of wizard or wise-man as a councilor, who conceives an "ultimate weapon" against their enemies- an hourglass of sorts that accelerates time against a target. However, during the course of the movie this weapon is stolen by the city's enemies (led by an evil queen or sorceress), who proceeds to use it against the city itself and all its inhabitants.

So the king sends out his armies to retrieve the artifact, all the while everyone and everything begins aging rapidly. Our boy-hero watches his older brother (now much older) set out with other knights on the quest, and there's a token romance between the boy and the king's daughter. The knights do not return, however, and the time-curse continues to wreak havoc on the city.

Ultimately, the boy (now a man) sets out to find his brother, the hourglass, and save the day. He finds his brother at a wreckage-site (I believe of a flying galleon), and they share a brief moment before the elder brother finally succumbs to old age. I'm sure I'm forgetting some other poignant details, but that's essentially the crux of it. Ends... if I remember correctly, with  the artifact being disabled and the evil queen/sorceress defeated.

Question is: what is this movie titled?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per User25830's comments above, the movie in question is the 1996 made-for-TV film "[To the Ends of Time](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117929/)" (AKA "[Ritter der Zeit](http://www.markusrothkranz.com/end_of_time.html)").

> "a full 35mm theatrical motion picture that got world-wide release
>   which had over 400 visual effects shots, a philharmonic orchestra
>   soundtrack with 100 man choir, major epic battle scenes with dangerous
>   pyrotechnics and stunts, 30,000 sq feet of indoor sets and a full
>   sized galleon ship set outdoors. Markus Rothkranz wrote and directed
>   this period fantasy which featured over 300 extras, all of which
>   needed custom elaborate medeival costumes. Markus also personally
>   built over 200 miniature models for the film and helped pound nails on
>   many of the sets, including the one above, which of course he also
>   designed. All the sets were built by mainly four people. It was quite
>   a big screen accomplishment, proving you don't need huge crews and a
>   hundred million dollars to make an elaborate film. Just spirit, desire
>   and resourcefulness."

Comment: Man, they *really* wanted to get the rights for "O Fortuna" for that trailer.

Answer (score 3):

When you mentioned the flying galleons I thought it may be "[The Time Bandits](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081633/)", but the rest of the plot doesn't match up.

Comment: Listing one movie that it definitely isn't is not an answer.

Comment: Apparently I'm not able to officially answer my own topic.
Guess I'll put it to rest in commments, then:

I'll be damned, but the title just occurred to me. It's "To the Ends of Time." Here's a trailer for the interested: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gzs3Z4UeVEQ

Well, that's settled then.
Thank you all for your time.

Comment: @user25830 if you can't post an answer then you could edit your question to make it clear to others that you already have an answer.